# Calling disable() on FormArray child resets dirty state

Tags: angular

In Angular I have a form like the following

```
  const form = this.fb.group({
      id: 1,
      unique_identifier: "a-b-c-d-e",
      name: "foo",
      last_update: "2020-07-31 12:22:22",
      items: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          name: "Item 1",
          value: "1",
        }),
      ]),
    });
```

When I call `form.get('items').markAsDirty()` the dirty property of the FormArray is true, as expected.

```
form.get('items').markAsDirty();

console.log(form.get('items').dirty) // = true
```

When I call `disable()` or `enable()` on one of the children of the FormArray after that, the dirty property of the FormArray is false. I didn't expect that

```
form.get('items').markAsDirty();

console.log(form.get('items').dirty) // = true

form.get('items').at(0).get('value').disable();

console.log(form.get('items').dirty) // = false
```

Does anyone know why that is? Or is this a bug in Angular?

See also Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-koyisp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `(<FormArray>this.form.get('items')).at(0).get('value').disable({onlySelf: true});` this should do the job for you

Comment: Thanks! That works. Is this expected behaviour in Angular?

Comment: Here we need to disable only specific field rather than the whole form and for that we used `{onlySelf: true}` I am moving this to as an answer you can accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable FormArray's particular field by passing `{onlySelf: true}` in `.disable()` see the below example.

```
(<FormArray>this.form.get('items')).at(0).get('value').disable({onlySelf: true});

console.log(form.get('items').dirty) // = true (should be true now)
```